# Alternative for Cross Join with a Table having Single Row (Multiple Columns)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, cross-join

I have a table for Configuration - tblConfig as Shown below

```
-------------------------------------------
| SiteCode  |  CompanyCode | CompanyGroup |
-------------------------------------------
| AISH78    |  SPWI85      |SFTIT         |
-------------------------------------------
```

And another table tblData With More than 10K rows.

I want to write a query to return tblData Table Rows along with Columns of tblConfig tables.

Eg:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SiteCode  |  CompanyCode | CompanyGroup | tblDataCol1 | tblDataCol2|.....etc
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| AISH78    |  SPWI85      |SFTIT         |    1        |  XY       | ....etc
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| AISH78    |  SPWI85      |SFTIT         |    2        |  MN       | ....etc
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| AISH78    |  SPWI85      |SFTIT         |    3        |  PQ       | ....etc
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
...
...
..etc
```

I Know i can write a cross Join Query as

```
 Select * from tblConfig
 Cross Join tblData
```

But above Query is affecting performance as tblData is having more than 10K rows. (I have few other queries after this cross Join).

Is there any alternative for cross join for the above scenario.?
Please help.

Comment: Do you really not have any column which is common between your 2 tables?

Comment: Create a stored procedure that returns top n records and returns different resuils depending on an input parameter ?

Comment: how big is `tblConfig`  ?

Comment: If `tblConfig ` really has one row (and will only ever have one row) then you do not have a performance issue with a `Cross Join`. What is the real problem? Do you see better performance when you don't cross join this table in?

Comment: @Squirrel - tblConfig have only 1 row with 3-4 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm... you don't need to use a cross join. You can use a regular inner join as well. However, might be that the Optimizer changes it into a cross join after all - you will have to try if performance suits your requirements:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(
  SiteCode NVARCHAR(10),
  CompanyCode NVARCHAR(10),
  CompanyGroup NVARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES ('AISH78','SPWI85', 'SFTIT')


DECLARE @t2 TABLE(
  c1 NVARCHAR(10),
  c2 NVARCHAR(10),
  c3 NVARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES ('AAA','BBB', 'CCC'), ('DDD','EEE', 'FFF'), ('GGG','HHH', 'III')

SELECT t1.*, t2.*
  FROM @t2 t2
  JOIN @t1 t1 ON t1.SiteCode = t1.SiteCode
```

Comment: There is a slight deduction in duration of my query ~30-40 ms.